# How to know which AR model is reprentative of stock prices?

Tags: time-series, self-study, autoregressive, finance

I have an exercise like this:

> Consider the following three AR models that a researcher suggests might be a reasonable model of stock market prices:
> $$\begin{align}
> p(t) &= p(t−1) + u(t) \\[6pt]
> p(t) &= 0.5p(t−1) + u(t) \\[6pt]
> p(t) &= 0.7p(t−1) + u(t) \\[6pt]
> \end{align}$$ where $\{ u(t) \}$ is i.i.d with mean 0.

Do you think which of those processes  is likely to represent stock market prices? Could you suggest me the direction to do it? For example if I can use the Ljung-box test or/and the stationary to find the answer.

Comment: Is $p_t$ really the price here? If so, I would argue that none of these models work because they allow for negative prices. If you're meant to ignore that, then consider how you might be able to easily exploit some of these models if they were actually true, and note that such simple opportunities do not really exist.

Comment: @RichardHardy thank you for this suggestion, whereby I found my explication.

Comment: @ChrisHaug you're right, I will mention it as well

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** None of these are a very good representation of stock prices.  Nevertheless, out of the three choices, one choice is less problematic than the other two.  Think about what tends to happen to the time-series variable in the latter two cases as time progresses.  Does this reflect the actual behaviour you observe from stock prices?  Why/why not?